# Finding the family of functions satisfying $f(x + y)=f(x)f(y) - f(x-y)$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

> What are the functions $f$ such that $f(x + y)=f(x)f(y) - f(x-y)$?

I got
$$f(0) = 2$$
$$f(x)=f(-x)$$
$$\left(f(a)^2 - 4\right)\left(f(b)^2 - 4\right) \ge 0$$
$$f'(0)=0$$
Can this be solved using the given information? Is $f(x) = a^x + \frac{1}{a^x}$ the only solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Attention, $2f(x) = f(0)f(x)$ does not imply $f(0) = 2$. For instance the function $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$ is solution of your problem but $f(0) = 0 \neq 2$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solution of the functional equation $g(x)g(z) = g(x+z)+g(x-z)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1553136/solution-of-the-functional-equation-gxgz-gxzgx-z)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x)=2 \cos x$ satisfies all the conditions given here.
$$f(x+y)+f(x-y)= 4 \cos x \cos y= 2 f(x) f(y) ~~~(1)$$
$$f(0)=2, f(-x)=f(x),  (4 \cos^2 a-4)(4\cos^2 b-4)=16 \sin^2 a \\sin^2 b \ge 0$$
and $f'(x) =\sin x, f'(0)= 0.$ Also $f(x)=2\cos x= e^{ix}+ e^{-ix}=a^x+a^{-x} \implies a=e^{i}$.